# Should we retag identification questions once they're answered?

Tags: discussion, retagging, identification-questions

We have a lot of [identification](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) questions now, and I wonder: would it would be useful to retag these with the identified plant/pest/disease when this has been determined?

For example, [this question about identifying a vine](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/943/im-having-trouble-identifying-this-vine-in-my-yard) might be retagged [morning-glory](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morning-glory) if the first (and currently only) answer turns out to be correct.

My thinking is that, if you've got some idea of what your plant/pest/disease might be and you're googling for help in making a positive identification, you might find one of these questions and have it answer your question.

(The same line of thinking goes for [diagnosis](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagnosis) questions too.)

Answer (score 10):

Tagging is used primarily to catalog what a question is about. If an answer makes the original question relevant to another category (in this case, Morning Glories), then it should be tagged as such.

I know it seems a bit extraneous, but if a question turns out to be about Morning Glories, it should be cataloged as such.

Comment: i've edited the Tag Wiki accordingly